# Some times route plotted on google maps not clearly displayed in javascript on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an app using phone gap which have the functionality to draw route between two location on Google map but it some times draws the route on map and hides some times. My code is below:

```
var gmarkers = [];

function drawRoute(addressCurrent, addessDestination) {
    console.log("Inside draw root");
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDirection'), mapOptions);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var request = {
        origin: addressCurrent,
        destination: addessDestination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: '#0000ff',
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation = new Object();
            endLocation = new Object();
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                    startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                    createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address);
                }
                endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
                endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    var dist_dur = "";
                    if (steps[j].distance && steps[j].distance.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].distance.text;
                    if (steps[j].duration && steps[j].duration.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].duration.text;
                    for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                        polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
            polyline.setMap(map);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            console.log("Outside draw root");
            createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "end", endLocation.address);
            // == create the initial sidebar ==                                                
        }
    });
}

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
    // alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var iconImage;
    if (label == "start") {
        iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/start.png",
        // This marker is 30 pixels wide by 55 pixels tall.
        new google.maps.Size(30, 55),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is at 16,47.
        new google.maps.Point(16, 47));
    } else {
        iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/marker.png",
        // This marker is 30 pixels wide by 55 pixels tall.
        new google.maps.Size(30, 55),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is at 16,47.
        new google.maps.Point(16, 47));
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: iconImage,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });
    marker.myname = label;
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

This code is working well with ripple emulator but the problem with when its running on Android device

Comment: `var gmarkers='[]';` supposed to be an array or string?

Comment: `gmarkers` has to be defined as `var gmarkers = [];`. Otherwise there is error reported `Uncaught TypeError: Object [] has no method 'push' `.

Comment: I already declared gmarkers as var gmarkers=[ ];

Comment: Do you call `drawRoute()` many times in a row? For example more than 10 times? If you do that you will get `status: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` and that route won't be displayed. You are not checking status value other then `OK`. Put `console.log('status: ' + status);` before `if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {` and try to repeat the error.

Comment: I calling drawRoute() function upon button click event.

Comment: Other possibility is that current and/or destination address is wrong/empty. From your code it is not clear how those values are created.